# How to set a duplicate tab keybinding in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

I tried to follow the Microsoft Docs instructions to set a keybinding for opening a duplicate tab with the following line `{ "command": "duplicateTab", "keys": "ctrl+shift+d" }`, but, when I press the key combination, it opens a new tab without duplicating the position (the folder where I am) of the current tab. Here's my json file:

```
  "keybindings":
    [
       ...
        //This makes a copy of the current tab and opens it.
        { "command": "duplicateTab", "keys": "ctrl+shift+d" }
    ]
```

Comment: [This open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3158) may be what you're interested in. It seems like what you are experiencing is currently intended.

Comment: @CallumWatkins Thanks for the reference. Then I don't quite understand the function of "duplicate" tab/pane as introduced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/panes). If I have a vim open, that command won't open a new vim either.

Comment: If you have a CMD tab open, duplicate will create a new CMD tab. If the tab is instead PowerShell or WSL etc. it will open a new one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I've written up a longer version of the answer to this over at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/terminal/pull/449. To keep it short:

Typically, the "new tab" and "split pane" actions will always open a new tab/pane in whatever the `startingDirectory` is for that profile. However, on other platforms, it's common for new tabs to automatically use the working directory of the current tab as the starting directory for a new tab. This allows the user to quickly multitask in a single directory.

Unfortunately, on Windows, it's tricky to determine what the current working directory ("CWD") for a process is. Even if we were able to look it up, not all applications actually set their CWD as they navigate. Notably, Windows PowerShell doesn't change its CWD as you `cd` around the file system! Duplicating the CWD of PowerShell automatically would almost always be wrong.

Fortunately, there's a workaround. Applications can emit a special escape sequence to manually tell the Terminal what the CWD should be.

For example, for `cmd.exe`:

`cmd` uses the `%PROMPT%` environment variable to configure the prompt. You can easily prepend the prompt with the command to set the CWD with the following command:

```
set PROMPT=$e]9;9;$P$e\%PROMPT%
```

This will append `$e]9;9;$P$e\` to your current prompt. When cmd evaluates this prompt, it'll replace

- the `$e` with the escape character
- the `$p` with the current working directory

Comment: for bash it causes me a error:
-bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
-bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 2: `_update_ps1; ; printf "\e]9;9;%s\e\\" "$(wslpath -w "$PWD")"'

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of WT has this shortcut

You can duplicate tab by keys "cmd + shift + d"